# MS Money 2003 on Windows 10 missing IE6 components

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-6, microsoft-money

I am still using MS Money 2003. It was working fine on my Windows 8 64Bit system.
After upgrading to Windows 10, I get the error "Some needed components of Internet Explorer 6 are missing" when I attempt to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach mentioned in this article worked for me
https://techjourney.net/microsoft-money-requires-internet-explorer-6-to-function-properly-error-in-windows-10/